# Axiom of Completeness is equivalent to the cut property for $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am required to prove that the ***Axiom of Completeness*** is equivalent to the ***Cut Property of Real Numbers***.

The Following in my attempt so far

*Proof.* $(\Rightarrow)$. By hypothesis $A,B$ are non-empty sets bounded above and below respectively. Now define the set $H = \{h\in\mathbf{R}\ |\ h\ \text{ is a lower bound for }B\}$ and note that $A\subseteq H$. The axiom of completeness assures us that $\sup B$ exists and by exercise $\textbf{1.3.3}$ it is apparent that $\sup H = \inf B$. Now Let $c = \sup H = \inf B$ and assume that $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ respectively, then $b\geq c$ and since $a\in H$ it follows that $a\leq c$.

$(\Leftarrow).$ Now let $E\subseteq\mathbf{R}$ such that $E\neq\varnothing$ and is bounded above $\dots\dots$

---

I dont know where should i start for the converse in particular i am not sure how to partition $\mathbf{R}$ given the set $E$. Any hints and only hints would be appreciated.

The full statement of the cut property and exercise $\textbf{1.3.3}$ is as follows.

> If $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, disjoint sets with $A\cup B = \mathbf{R}$
>   and $a < b$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, then there exists
>   $c\in\mathbf{R}$ such that $x\leq c$ whenever $x\in A$ and $x\ge c$
>   whenever $x\in B$.
>
> $\textbf{1.3.3}$ Let $A$ be non-empty and bounded below, and define $B
>  = \{b\in\mathbf{R}|b\text{ is a lower bound for A}\}$, then $\sup B = \inf A$.

Comment: A side comment: your proofs will be clearer if you explain to the reader ahead of time which direction you're doing. Taking a quick glance at what you've written, I'm not sure what you've done and what you're still doing.

Comment: @goblin My apologies

Comment: You have nothing to apologize for; I was giving practical advice, not trying to be critical.

Comment: @goblin Is it clear now or should i edit it again ?

Comment: Yep, that's a lot better,

Comment: The way I'd proceed is to let $A = \{a \in \mathbb{R} : \exists e \in E(a < e)\}$. Then let $B = \{b \in \mathbb{R} : \forall a \in A(b \geq a)\}.$

Comment: @goblin Thank you very much. I would never have thought of that in a million years

Comment: For the converse, if $S$ is a non-empty subset  of $\Bbb R$ and $S$ has an upper bound, let $B$ be the set of upper bounds for $S$ and let $A$ be the complement of $B.$

Comment: The reason we say "the" reals is that if F,G are ordered fields with the cut property then F,G are isomorphic, so it doesn't matter which one you call the "real" reals.